# What is the actual film manufacturer reference for the film response data?

Tags: color-management, lut

I would like to understand if there is some reference for all this film response data and if/how it was validated.

https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/datafiles/colormanagement/luts/film_response/

Thanks.

P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original dataset was taken from the [Computer Vision Laboratory](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/CAVE/), and more specifically [this portion of the site](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/CAVE/software/softlib/dorf.php). The research PDF is available [here](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/CAVE/publications/pdfs/Grossberg_CVPR03.pdf).

The response data didn't include the primary colours, nor the log encoding as the results are normalized. They are essentially junk Instagram-esque filters sadly.